# Second Activity is getting loaded but not displaying any Views (TextView or Image) on it

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I created a new `Activity` in my android project named **Second.xml** and **Second.java** class
and added a `TextView` and `Background Image` to it.

And I created a `Button` on my default `Activity` **MainActivity.class** and wrote following code on `onClick()` event of the `Button` to navigate to **`second activity`**:

```
  b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class));

            }
        });
```

App is successfully running in emulator and also navigating on second activity on clicking `Button`, But - neither the `TextView` is displayed nor the `Image` is loaded on **Second.xml**

Any idea why it may happen. Plz help.

Comment: post your second Activity code.

Comment: post your second Class code

Comment: post your code of `Second.class` and `Second.xml` as well.

Comment: Have you inflated your second activity layout in `onCreate()` method using `setContentView()` method ? @Mustafa

Comment: Have you added your second.xml to your Second.class correctly??

Comment: Yup, I forgot to include setContentView() method. I knw its silly. Still a novice to android. Thanx fr ur help though ..

Comment: @Mustafa Just delete or close your question if its solved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class));

            }
        });
```

with this:

```
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```